# Expire or timelimit socket.io connection in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I've dug around in the docs but don't see anything that specifically handles this so I'm looking for a manageable workaround to effectively 'expire' or disconnect a socket.io client after a certain amount of time. Obviously on node.js I need any events handing this to be async and non thread blocking.

It seems to me to be a bad example of what I want to achieve, but consider:

A user connects to a room with a max time of 3 minutes:

```
socket.on('connection', function(params){
   var maxTime = params.maxTime; 
   socket.join(params.roomId);
   setTimeout(function{
   socket.leave(params.roomId);
}, 180000)
});
```

I feel like this would work for 1 connection fine, but seems like it would cause some serious overhead should I have say 10000 concurrent clients connected to a range of rooms?

Is there a better or accepted way of tackling this?

Comment: Hey @OliverJ90; which solution did you use in the end? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not track the connection time on the client side and not use any server resources for that?

Comment: As I understand it, this leaves it open to abuse if it's just client side js

Comment: What if the client has lost the connection, how do i notice to the server about the disconnection